# Why is my table doing this?

Tags: html, css

I've done everything to try work this out but here's my problem:

[image]

It happened after wrapping my table in a form, Anyways, if possible I need this centred unless my centring is correct. Please tell me what I did wrong and what I should do next time!

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Game</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#336699">


<div id="login">
    <form id="login" action="login.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Login</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Username: <input type="text"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password: <input type="password"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit"></td></tr>



    </table>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#header{
    text-align: center;
}

#login{
    font-family: "Arial", "serif";
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px;

}

#table,th,td{
    border: solid 1px;
}
```

Comment: You have two elements with the same id (login), you should consider changing it to a class or renaming one of the ids

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the login ID, you have given it 15% width. Increase it to 50 or 60% and it will work.

```
#login{
    font-family: "Arial", "serif";
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px;

}
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/vcz72sxy/1/

**EDIT**

I have changed some code from the previous poster, added the align value within the table to center it.

http://jsfiddle.net/kc3gh83h/1/

Comment: You're example doesn't seem to be working unless its just on my screen lol

Comment: Sorry @TaylorStevens the width value didnt save on my jsfiddle lol. Take a look at the revised version - used Dans code below

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Use this and you'll be set! Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hfnqbboj/2

HTML

```
<body bgcolor="#336699">
<div id="login">
<form id="login" action="login.php" method="post">
<table align="center">
    <tr><td>Login</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Username: <input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password: <input type="password"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#header{
text-align: center;
}

#login{
font-family: "Arial", "serif";
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
text-align: center;
border: solid 1px;

}

#table,th,td{
border: solid 1px;
}
```

Comment: I require that border around it though

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. You've called id="login" twice, you can only call it once. So the rule for #login is being applied twice. If that was intentional, you want to change it to a class (.login)
2. The second, which takes care of the issue directly (as @Dan and @JSG have said) - change your width.

Comment: I feel so stupid, The problem was the 1st answer, I renamed my form to loginForm and it sorted the problem